# Adding a new dictionary item to a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```py
cities={

    'city1':{

         'name':'sydney',

         'country':'australia',

         'desc':'beautiful'

},
 
   'city2':{

        'name':'toronto',

        'country':'canada',

        'desc':'amazing',

    }

}

cities['city3']:"{'name':'Tokyo','country':'japan','desc':'lots of earthquakes’}"

for keys,values in cities.items():
    print(f"{keys}--->{values}”)
```

This is my code. I am new to python and learning dictionaries as of now. I am trying to add a dictionary to an existing dictionary but it doesn’t work. I have no errors and still only get the first two cities info. I think my syntax must be wrong. Can anyone help me with this please>?

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: you should use `=` instead of `:` . `cities['city3'] = {'name':'Tokyo','country':'japan','desc':'lots of earthquakes'}`

Comment: oh god... I feel so stupid... thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your insertion code to:

```
cities['city3'] = {'name':'Tokyo','country':'japan','desc':'lots of earthquakes'}
```

You probably don't want to add it as a string, so leave away the quatation marks. Furthermore, there is an erroneous quatation mark at the end of the description.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chainmap from collections, it chains all dictionary into one.

```
from collections import ChainMap
city3 = {'city3': {'name':'Tokyo','country':'japan','desc':'lots of earthquakes'}}
cities = ChainMap(cities,city3)
print(dict(cities))
```